# Angular 6 autosuggest search box

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I was following this tutorial https://medium.com/@nacimidjakirene/angular-search-autosuggest-with-observables-6f42987f80e6 and i want to do it in angular 6.

How do i convert this into angular 6 compatible code ?

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.queryField.valueChanges
    .debounceTime(200)
    .distinctUntilChanged()
    .switchMap((query) =>  this._searchService.search(query))
    .subscribe( result => { if (result.status === 400) { return; } else {   this.results = result.json().artists.items; }
  });
  }
}
```

I converted this myself but i am having error on **this.logframe.searchEmployee(term).subscribe()**

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.registerationForm.valueChanges
    .pipe(
      debounceTime(200),
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      switchMap((term) => this.logframe.searchEmployee(term).subscribe()),
    );
  }
```

if you have some alternatives on this one please let me know :)

EDIT:
Fixed my problem :)

I just need to tweak Fan Cheung code by getting specific formcontrol then also add catcherror so that it wont go complete after 404 on null

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.registerationForm.get('name').valueChanges
    .pipe(
      debounceTime(200),
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      switchMap((term) => this.logframe.searchEmployee(term).pipe(catchError(err => of('null')))),
    ).subscribe(
      val => console.log(val)
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

subscribe return `Subscription` which cannot be consumed by `switchMap`
if `this.logframe.searchEmployee(term)` return Observable then try below code

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.registerationForm.valueChanges
    .pipe(
      debounceTime(200),
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      switchMap((term) => this.logframe.searchEmployee(term)),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed my problem :)

I just need to tweak Fan Cheung code by getting specific formcontrol then also add catcherror so that it wont go complete after 404 on null

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.registerationForm.get('name').valueChanges
    .pipe(
      debounceTime(200),
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      switchMap((term) => this.logframe.searchEmployee(term).pipe(catchError(err => of('null')))),
    ).subscribe(
      val => console.log(val)
    );
  }
```